# How to build a JSON response made up of multiple models in C# wcf

Tags: c#, arrays

I am using C# in Visual Studio 2010 and creating a WCF service.

```
[
    {
        "QuizCategory":"Basic Skills",
        "QuizID":["1","2"],
        "QuizShortName":["Career","Beginner"]
    },
    {
        "QuizCategory":"General",
        "QuizID":["3","4"],
        "QuizShortName":["General","General # 2"]
    }
]
```

I am getting the above results in json result, but I need to show like below result, like dictionary by dictionary:

```
[
    {
        "QuizCategory":"Basic Skills", 
        Subclasses: 
        [
            {
                "QuizID":1,"QuizShortName":"Career"
            },
            {
                "QuizID":2,
                "QuizShortName":"Beginner"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "QuizCategory":"General",      
        Subclasses: 
        [
            {
                "QuizID":3,
                "QuizShortName":"General"
            },
            {
                "QuizID":4,
                "QuizShortName":"General#2"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

StringBuilder jsonResult = new StringBuilder();
            List lstCNAInfo = new List();

```
        using (RestDataContext dc = new RestDataContext())
        {
            CNAClassInfo objCNAInfo;
            var records = dc.GetCNAClasses(Status);

            foreach (var rec in records)
            {
                ArrayList listQID = new ArrayList();
                ArrayList listQSN = new ArrayList();
                String[] splitQID = rec.QuizId.Split(',');
                String[] splitQSN = rec.QuizShortName.Split('$');
                foreach (var varlist in splitQSN)
                {
                    listQSN.Add(varlist);
                }
                foreach (var varlist in splitQID)
                {
                    listQID.Add(varlist);
                }
                objCNAInfo = new CNAClassInfo();
                objCNAInfo.QuizCategory = rec.QuizCat;
                objCNAInfo.QuizID = listQID;
                objCNAInfo.QuizShortName = listQSN;                                        
                lstCNAInfo.Add(objCNAInfo);
            }
        }
        //Json serialzer
        DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(List<CNAClassInfo>));
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        serializer.WriteObject(ms, lstCNAInfo);
        jsonResult.Append(Encoding.Default.GetString(ms.ToArray()));
        ms.Close();
        return jsonResult.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: What does your class structure look like?  If you are using a JSON serializer it should be serializing the class structure of your object so garbage in garbage out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's serializing the response as you have shown is simply because that's how your class structure looks like.

If you want to get the expected output, make sure your structure looks like this:

```
public class Category
{
    public string QuizCategory {get;set;}
    public List<Subclasses> {get;set;}
}

public class Subclasses
{
     public int QuizID {get;set;}
     public string QuizShortName  {get;set;}

}
```

And when you serialize it, you serialize a `List<Category>`, which will contain one Category object per Quiz Category.

Comment: Ok I am new in coding can you help me in the code... 
from database we are getting this data
Basic Skills 1 Career
Basic Skills 2 Beginner
General         1 General
General    2 General # 2
How we code for above result
Thanx in advance

Comment: @Vinay how do you hydrate your objects from the database? i.e. Do you populate a DataTable, a DataSet, do you use Entity Framework, etc.? I would need to see your actual class structure before I can answer your question.

Comment: Data retrieving from database

Basic Skills 1,2 Career$Beginner
General 3,4 General$General # 2

var records = dc.GetCNAClasses(Status);

                foreach (var rec in records)
                {
      ' '
                }

Comment: Done please look in main question